# Multi part problem to prove functional relation of the exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, exponential-function

[image]

I'm worried about part (i) right now mostly. Part 3 is easy, and part 2 I can probably get after some work. I know that

$\exp(-z) = \large\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{-z^n}{n!} = 1-z+\frac{z^2}{2} - \frac{z^3}{6} + . . .$

I don't know how I can relate this to $\large\frac{1}{\exp(z)}$ though.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you are allowed to use the relation $\exp(z+w) = \exp(z)\exp(w)$. Use also (iii) and just notice that
$$
 1 = \exp(0) = \exp(z+(-z)) = \exp(z)\exp(-z).
$$

Comment: I don't think we're allowed to use that, i mean it says we have to prove it right?

Comment: It says *deduce* which means you can use it.

Comment: I don't see how that means I can use it.

Comment: When one says "prove A then deduce B" it means that you can use A to prove B.